# Writing to USB flash drive taking forever, unable to exit program using Ctrl + C

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, terminal, iso-image

I am trying to write an ISO to a USB drive using the following command:

```
sudo cp -v Downloads/archlinux-2021.02.01-x86_64.iso /dev/sdb
```

My flash drive has a blinking red light, which I believe means that it is being written to. After a while, the light stops blinking, but the terminal does not exit the program. There is no extra output or anything.

Is there a reason as to why the terminal does not exit the program? I have no way of telling if the ISO has been written to the drive or not.

Edit:

I have noticed that `Ctrl + C`, `Ctrl + Z`, and `Ctrl + /` all do nothing. It shows little symbols when I use the shortcuts, but nothing else happens.

Extra information:
OS: Arch Linux
Terminal: Konsole (This also happens on both of my computers, and also happens in TTY)